# C# Microsoft Graph: Contacts: ErrorAccessDenied

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-contacts

A while ago I created an application to create Outlook events in the calendars of our employees with Microsoft Graph in a background process. Now I want to expand the current application and also manage contacts.
First of all I want to created a new contact person.

Code that calls the GraphHelper.cs:

```
AuthenticationConfig config = AuthenticationConfig.ReadFromJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{config.ApiUrl}.default" };

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                                .Create($"{config.ClientId}")
                                .WithTenantId($"{config.Tenant}")
                                .WithAuthority(new Uri(config.Authority))
                                .WithClientSecret($"{config.ClientSecret}")
                                .Build();
            ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes[0]);
            GraphHelper.Initialize(authenticationProvider);
            
            string status = CreateContact().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

```
        private static async Task<string> CreateContact()
        {
            return await GraphHelper.CreateContact("admin@premed.be");
        }
```

GraphHelper.cs:

```
public static void Initialize(IAuthenticationProvider authProvider)
        {
            graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
        }
```

```
public static async Task<string> CreateContact(string userName)
        {
            var contact = new Contact
            {
                GivenName = "GivenNameTest",
                Surname = "SurnameTest",
                EmailAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>()
                {
                    new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "GivenNameTest.SurnameTest@hotmail.com",
                        Name = "GivenNameTest SurnameTest Test"
                    }
                },
                BusinessPhones = new List<String>()
                {
                    "+32489789654"
                }
            };
            try
            {
                await graphClient.Users[userName]
                    .Contacts
                    .Request()
                    .AddAsync(contact);
                return "OK";
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

When I run the code, I get an ErrorAccessDenied error "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

[image: Error Message]

But I don't understand why I get the error. For the autorisation I use the same functionality I used for the calendar. Also the same tenant, client-id and client secret is used. In the Azure portal all permissions are given.

[image: Permissions in Azure]

For example: creating an event is no problem.

```
public static async Task<string> CreateEvent(Event newEvent, string userName)
        {
            try
            {
                // POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
                var returnEvent = await graphClient.Users[userName]
                    .Events
                    .Request()
                    .Header("Prefer", "outlook.timezone=\"Europe/Paris\"")
                    .AddAsync(newEvent);

                return returnEvent.Id;
            }
            catch (ServiceException ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added more information and code.

Comment: I am curious to know , when you tried to call the contact API in graph explorer - POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts , is that working for you ?

Comment: Before I had give consent I was getting the same Error Access Denied, after I had given permissions in the permission tab, it was working for me.